# Print 3D coordinates of the selected point inside PCL visualizer

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am trying to print the 3D coordinates of the selected point using PCL. Below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/io.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>

using namespace std;

void pointPickingEventOccurred (const pcl::visualization::PointPickingEvent& event, void* viewer_void)
{
  std::cout << "[INOF] Point picking event occurred." << std::endl;

  float x, y, z;
  if (event.getPointIndex () == -1)
  {
     return;
  }
  event.getPoint(x, y, z);
  std::cout << "[INOF] Point coordinate ( " << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")" << std::endl;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("Cloud Viewer");
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr body (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("body.pcd", *body);
    viewer.addPointCloud (body,"body");
    viewer.registerPointPickingCallback (pointPickingEventOccurred, (void*)&viewer);
    viewer.spin();
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles without any error but it doesn't print any information in termainal. What's wrong here?

Comment: Is it possible that the function is always left via the "return" before the output?

Comment: @Yunnosch: Thank you very much. I put a `std::cout` statement but it is not printing anything on the terminal.

Comment: Do you see the first line of output, and what do you get for the point ID? Maybe it's always -1 like what @Yunnosch means. Do this: `std::cout << "[INOF] Point picking event occurred at id " << event.getPointIndex () << std::endl;`

Comment: @acraig5075: Please see the updated question. I added `std::cout << "[INOF] Point picking event occurred." << std::endl;`  this line in front of the callback. But still, it is not even printing this statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try holding down shift while left-clicking to pick a point.

Comment: This is a really stupid thing to ask.. It is working... I never knew about it that shift key is necessary.

Comment: Not stupid at all, you aren't the first to have this problem!